# Advice on using jquery ajax to return a excel file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a web page that has a bunch of fields, and GET EXCEL button. Currently, when the user presses the GET EXCEL button, a js script collects the data from the fields, concocts a url to the Action Controller:

in js:

```
$("excel-btn").onclick( function () {
//get selected parameters:
    p1 = $("#p1").val();
    p2 = $("#p2").val();
    p3 = $("#p3").val();

    window.location = "myController/getExcel?p1=" + p1 + "&p2=" + p2 + "&p3=" + p3;
});
```

In my controller action:

```
public ActionResult DownloadExcel(string p1, string p2, string p3)
{

            //go to the database and get the data, shove it into the file
            return File(ms, "application/ms-excel", "myfile.xls"); 
 }
```

Question: 
I would like to use jquery ajax to achieve the same result since I have more flexibility and can pass objects into the action, rather than append the required parameters to the query string. Is this possible? 
If so, what would ajax return in this case?

I am using asp.net MVC3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could the excel button just populate a form field with the variables and then submit it, without ajax?  So long as the content type is set to be application/ms-excel, it would prompt the user to open or save the file (or whatever the browser's default behavior seems to be).

This is essentially how I handle this issue, and seems to work fine.

Comment: thanks. Just one thing to clarify: content type  of what? The ajax call?

Comment: you'd be doing a traditional HTTP GET/POST, not an ajax call.  Make sure your response's content type is application/ms-excel (which, based on your code sample, looks like it is) and when the browser receives the response it will prompt the user to download the file.

Comment: I don't imagine it would have to.  Give it a try and tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

you can't ajax for this. you should use iframe's to create a ajax like download

Comment: Please elaborate in more detail what do you mean by "ajax like download". Keep in mind that what I am trying to achieve is avoid using getstring.

Comment: the point is, you can't get an excel file as a byte array and recompile with javascript. if you use a hidden iframe, you can hide the parameters. you can also use post for this.

Comment: The issue is purely easthetic. The user doesn't see the variables as the url is composed within JS. So the iframe would not achieve what I am trying to achive - pass an object to the Action, rather than a bunch of strings.